# Docker-compose up generates an error on Spring / MySQL application

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a container for my Spring/MySQL application. I'm quite new to Docker, so I read about some of its commands to learn more about it. First of all, I created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/spring-demo-app.jar spring-demo-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/spring-demo-app.jar"]
```

After creating the Dockerfile, I generated the jar file by using mvn install (the jar file was perfectly generated ).
Right after that, I created the docker-compose.yml that contains all the config for my app.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: karia
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - my_sql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  spring_app:
    image: spring-demo-app:latest
    container_name: spring_container
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/karia
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:
volumes:
  my_sql_data:
```

Then I created the build using `docker build -t spring-demo-app.jar .` . Well, I had my docker build and my app runs on port 8080. But whenever I'd run `docker-compose up`. I'd end up having an error. I tried to authenticate using `docker login` to resolve it yet it seemed like that wasn't the issue. Here is the error :

```
C:\Users\sadde\Desktop\SPRING\demo>docker login
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded

Logging in with your password grants your terminal complete access to 
your account.
For better security, log in with a limited-privilege personal access 
token. Learn more at 
https://docs.docker.com/go/access-tokens/
C:\Users\sadde\Desktop\SPRING\demo>docker-compose up
[+] Running 1/1
✘ spring_app Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
1.9s
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for spring-demo-app, repository does not exist or 
may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: Try the command `docker login` to login to Docker Hub using your Docker Hub username and password (you can create an account for free if you don't have it yet). You only need to do that once, after that it should work.

Comment: I already did `docker login` though. It authenticates me perfectly but right after authenticating, the `docker-compose up` would end up failing

Comment: The `docker build` command should be: `docker build -t spring-demo-app .` without `.jar`. What you specify after the `-t` is the tag for the Docker image, which your Docker Compose file expects to be `spring-demo-app`.

Comment: Good job, you figured it out. Thank you. I got another error though. `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one use of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is usually allowed`

Comment: Looks like you already have something running on your computer that is occupying port 3306. Do you have a local instance of MySQL running on your computer? Then stop it first, or map the port of the Docker container that runs MySQL to a different port than 3306.

Comment: That's also right ! Well, but I don't understand why that's correct. Doesn't the container have standalone ports compared to my machine?

Comment: You're mapping the port that's running in the container to a port on the host machine (localhost); that's how you make it possible to access the container from the host machine via the network. That port on localhost has to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Try building the docker image from docker compose. One example is provided below:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=local
    ports:
      - '18080:8080'
```